# java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #10: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

This is CountryDrawerListAdapter at inflation time in getView() I'm getting  java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #10: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

```
   public class CountryDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        private Viewholder mHolder;
        private InputStream mInputStream = null;
        private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        private List<String> mFilteredData = null;
        private ArrayList<String> mData;

        public CountryDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data, ListView list) {
            this.mContext =context;
            this.mFilteredData =data;
            this.mData =data;
            mLayoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        private static class Viewholder {
            TextView text;
            ImageView icon;
            CheckBox ch_box;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (mFilteredData ==null) {
                return 0;
            }
            else return  mFilteredData.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.a_clientslist_layout, null);
                mHolder = new Viewholder();
                mHolder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_client_name);
                mHolder.icon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.img_client_logo);
                vi.setTag(mHolder);
            }
            else {
                mHolder = (Viewholder) vi.getTag();
            }
            mHolder.text.setText(mFilteredData.get(position));

            Drawable d;
            try {
                String flags=null;
               /* "images/client_1.png"*/
                if(mFilteredData.get(position).length()>0)
                {
                    flags= mFilteredData.get(position).replaceAll(" ", "_");
                }
                d = Drawable.createFromStream(mContext.getAssets().open("flags/"+flags+".png"), null);
                if (d==null){
                    mHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }
                mHolder.icon.setBackground(d);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LogCat.e("IOException", "" + e.toString());

            }

            return vi;
        }
        public Filter getFilter() { return mFilter;
        }

        private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                final List<String> list = mData;
                int count = list.size();
                final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);
                String filterableString ;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    filterableString = list.get(i);
                    if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                        nlist.add(filterableString);
                    }
                }
                results.values = nlist;
                results.count = nlist.size();
                return results;
            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the Xml that will be inflate by adapter.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_client_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_img_size_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_img_size_hight"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/listvie_left_padding"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_client_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_textsize"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This my log Cat for display error.

```
        02-16 10:40:10.183    9565-9565/com.android.xyz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: com.android.xyz , PID: 9565
            **java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #10: You must supply a layout_width attribute.**
                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5948)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6117)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1831)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                    at com.android.xyz.adapter.CountryDrawerListAdapter.getView(CountryDrawerListAdapter.java:69)
                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
                    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
                    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:866)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(H
```

Comment: What value is in `drawer_img_size_width` attribute ?

Comment: Check what goes into @dimen/drawer_img_size_width . Probably you are not getting the right value there

Comment: i'm setting width and hight at runtime for diffrent dimensions.dimen name="drawer_img_size_width">42dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="drawer_img_size_hight">42dp</dimen>

Answer (score 0):

Try two things

1. Call super in getView method.
2. Make width of LinearLayout as MatchParent.